# Regex to find number or none of spaces in a file use Visual Studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I Need to replace all the following samples with `<#= ObjectType #>`

```
<#= DatabaseName #>.<#= Table.Name #>
<#=DatabaseName#>.<#=Table.Name#>
<#=  DatabaseName  #>.<#=  Table.Name  #>
<#=DatabaseName #>.<#= Table.Name#>
```

As you see All of this samples start with `<#=` and can continued by some spaces or none then `DatabaseName` and again can continued by some spaces or none then `#>.<#=` and again can continued by some spaces or none then `Table.Name` then some spaces or non and at the end `#>`

I try to use Visual Studio 2010 Find and replace files so what is your suggestion regex to match this samples?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Oded Is not the question clear enough? Replace some samples with specific string

Comment: The question is clear. What efforts you have put into solving it and where you are stuck is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will do what you asked (tested with your examples), using the [Visual Studio regular expressions syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx):

```
^\<\#=:b*DatabaseName:b*\#\>\.\<\#=:b*Table\.Name:b*\#\>$
```

I am anchoring to both the start `^` and end `$` of the line, though you may not want to.

Also, `<`, `#`, `>` and `.` all need escaping.

`:b*` means any number of spaces or tabs.